# how to resolve startig stoppinf http client in activiti-rest

Tags: activiti

i work with activiti-rest 5.22, and j2ee my problem is that i connect each time to the engine to be able to realize functionalities like list processes when i authenticate to the process and for example i want to list the process listre at each he shows me this:

```
Infos: Starting the default HTTP client
Info: Stopping the default HTTP client
Infos: Starting the default HTTP client
Infos: Starting the default HTTP client
```

my activity connection function activiti:

```
 private static ClientResource getClientResource (String uri) {
       ClientResource resource = new ClientResource (uri);
       resource.setChallengeResponse (ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC,
               "kermit", "kermit");


           return resource;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably a logging level configuration, I recommend you to take a look at the documentation: https://www.activiti.org/5.x/userguide/#loggingConfiguration

The configuration should be set to none